# observeValueForKeyPath doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

This my first time using KVO in an iOS project and I wanted to observe the changes of my two UILabel's after getting my position by GPS, and keep notifying me. when I run the project I got my 2 labels showing the date and they are changing by time, but `observeValueForKeyPath` doesn't work.

```
@implementation GpsViewController{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocation *crnLoc;
}

@synthesize gpsView;
@synthesize gpsModel;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    gpsView = [[GpsView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widthtScreen,heightScreen)];
    [self.view addSubview:gpsView];
    [self initLocation];
}

- (void)initLocation 
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self showAlert];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    crnLoc = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"position long : %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude]);
    NSLog(@"position lat : %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.latitude]);
    gpsView.longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.longitude];
    [gpsView.longitudeLabel addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"long" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
    gpsView.latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f",crnLoc.coordinate.latitude];
    [gpsView.latitudeLabel addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"lat" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
 }

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"long"]) {
        NSLog(@"observe1");
    }
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"lat"]) {
        NSLog(@"observe2");
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all one of you string values in observeValueForKeyPath: is not "lat". You have "long" twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be more like this:

```
[gpsView.longitudeLabel addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

and in

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context;
```

your object is the corresponding label, so you could check for

```
if object == gpsView.longitudeLabel
```

Comment: yes, because the key is actualy the var of your label, like latitudeLabel.text = "1234". So you can access it via the key "text". Same is for textColor or so on..!

Comment: I tired it and it works ! but when I started my project I followed this tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/understanding-key-value-observing-coding/ . you can see that he used name and age as keypath . how it's possible then ?!

Comment: it's because the object Children has the variables "name" & "age" created by the author. So if he makes a instance of it, like child1 ... it takes the variables of "name" and "age", so you can KVO these for all object instances of Children

Comment: got it !! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can't just create any string inside `forKeyPath`. This determines the name of variable you are observing, so you can use for example "text" as `forKeyPath` if you want to observe changes in text.

Comment: if I will put text for both of them how can I see the difference in observeValueForKeyPath ?

Comment: You can compare object == latitudeLabel or longitudeLabel